# How to convert objects in dataframe to floats?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert all numbers in a dataframe to floats. So far I have had success except with a percent column. I get the error 'invalid literal for float: 0.00%' but it seems to be working for everything else. Here is my code so far:

```
def clean():
    rawdata = concat()
    rawdata = rawdata[['Channel','Advertiser Domain','Bids','Imp.','Avg. Bid CPM (USD)','Revenue (USD)','eCPM (USD)','Wins','Date']]     
    rawdata[['Bids','Imp.','Avg. Bid CPM (USD)','Revenue (USD)','eCPM (USD)','Wins']] \
    = rawdata[['Bids','Imp.','Avg. Bid CPM (USD)','Revenue (USD)','eCPM (USD)','Wins']].\
    replace([',','%'],'').astype(float)
    return rawdata
```

Solved:

```
def clean():
    rawdata = concat()
    rawdata = rawdata[['Channel','Advertiser Domain','Bids','Imp.','Avg. Bid CPM (USD)','Revenue (USD)','eCPM (USD)','Wins','Date']]     
    for col in ['Bids','Imp.','Wins']:
        rawdata[col] = rawdata[col].str.replace(',','').str.replace('%','')
    for com in ['Bids','Imp.','Avg. Bid CPM (USD)','Revenue (USD)','eCPM (USD)','Wins']:
        rawdata[com] = rawdata[com].astype(float)
    return rawdata.sort('Revenue (USD)', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Sorry are these strings or integers you're converting, for the % one you could strip the % sign off and then cast it, also can you post raw data to show us what it looks like, thanks

Comment: to be honest im not entirely sure. When i pull rawdata.ix[0] it shows datatype as object.

Comment: It's probably a string then, how come you're replacing commas also?

Comment: some columns are formatted with commas, 'Bids' and 'Imp.' for example, while 'Wins' is a percent

Comment: I couldn't understand what this line did `rawdata = concat()`

Comment: concat() is a separate function outside of clean()

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `replace` to include `regex=True`:

```
rawdata = rawdata.replace([',','%'],'', regex=True).astype('float')
```